# Handling NullPointerException in Lists

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a program where I have to code to get the mode in an array.I have that solved here.I wanted to make the program behave better by dealing with any "null" values without returning any text on the console in "red". Is there a message I can display? I have done the following but it wont work.

Thanks in advance

```
public static List<Integer> getMode(int[] values) throws NullPointerException,NoSuchElementException {
     if(values == null)
         throw new NullPointerException("The argument cannot be null");


      HashMap<Integer,Integer> freqs = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();


      for (int val : values) {
        Integer freq = freqs.get(val);
        freqs.put(val, (freq == null ? 1 : freq+1));
      }

      int mode = 0;
      int maxFreq = 0;

      for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : freqs.entrySet()) {
        int freq = entry.getValue();
        if (freq > maxFreq) {
          maxFreq = freq;
          mode = entry.getKey();
        }
      }

      List<Integer> modes = new LinkedList<Integer>();
      for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : freqs.entrySet()) {
          int freq = entry.getValue();
          if (freq == maxFreq) {
              modes.add(entry.getKey());
          }
      }

      return modes;
}
```

Comment: why not using try catch instead of throw an Exception?

Comment: You could print an error message (either through System.out or System.err) and return an empty list on a null value. If you don't want a stacktrace printed you either need a try-catch around whatever call you make to this method that ignores a thrown exception, or you can't throw an exception at all.

Comment: Just replace your throw statement with `if (values == null) return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;`

Comment: 'throws NullPointerException' this code makes me wanna cry, you should handle your code to avoid the runtime nullpointerexception.. if you really want to throw an exception, throw some checked exception like IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.  What "null values" are you trying to deal with?  Is it just the initial `if (values == null)` case or something else?

Comment: `Is there a message I can display?` You can display any message you want. What message do you **want** to display?